# refactoring and optimization the class

Tags: java

There is repetition here and would appreciate help in improving this code.  Suggestions? Here's the framework for it:

```
Class Author {
  private Integer id;

  public static List<Book> sortBooksAlphabetically( Author a ) {
    Integer id = a.id;
    if (id == null) { return null; }
    List<Book> list = getAllBooksForAuthor( id );
    // do some sorting and return list
  }

  public static List<Book> sortBooksReverseAlphabetically( Integer id ) {
    if (id == null ) { return null; }
    List<Book> list = getAllBooksForMusician( id );
    // do some sorting and return list
  }

  public static List<Book> sortBooksByPopularity( Integer id ) {
    if (id == null ) { return null; }
    List<Book> list = getAllBooksForAuthor( id );
    // do some sorting and return list
  }

  public static List<Book> getAllBooksForAuthor( Integer id ) {
     if (id == null ) throw new NullPointerException();
     ...
     return listOfBooks;
  }
}
```

Comment: http://qconlondon.com/london-2009/presentation/Null+References:+The+Billion+Dollar+Mistake ;-)

Comment: Try not to use static classes. When is int going to be null? if id==null then java will already throw a NullPointerException no need to throw another one.

Comment: @RobertSnyder "sneaking" `NullPointerException`s are never a good idea...

Comment: Just one "side remark": you say you want to refactor and optimize the class, fine; but what is this class supposed to do to begin with?

Comment: OK, this is very, very confusing. Why is `id` a parameter of the sorting functions of lists? Why do I have the sneaking suspiscion that the `id` passed as an argument here is always the id of the enclosing `Author` instance?

Comment: @fge I would never tell anyone to be sneaky with any exception, but this is a clear violation of DRY. The compiler will throw a NullPointerException if there is no ID supplied, or if the Author does not return any results. So don't repeat it. I would rather use inheritance and polymorphism to solve this problem.

Comment: @RobertSnyder while I agree with you, I suspect the problem here is much deeper than that. Dubious NPE handling is the least of the OP's concern here :/

Comment: @fge I wish I could have given you 2+'s :) 1 for the use of dubious and 2 for hitting the nail on the head.

Answer (score 3):

Tentative answer...

First of all, it looks like you didn't include the source of the *full* `Author` class. Where is the list of `Book`s for that author, for instance?

Second: you seem to want methods to sort this inner list of books for a given author; why, then, pass the id of the author as an argument? You should have a lookup method for an `Author` given its id -- but this lookup method should not be a method of one `Author` instance; at worst, it should be a static method in the `Author` class. What is your backend like? How do you look up an author by its id eventually?

Third: the JDK has `Collections.sort()`; and given that you want to have a sorted list of books according to several criteria, you want to write several `Comparator`s for that book. See below for a solution to that.

Fourth, and not the least: you should not operate on the list in the `Author` class itself, but on a copy of that list.

Given these four points above, here are some code extracts...

First: how to return a `List<Book>` from an author -- don't return the list itself but at least an unmodifiable version of it:

```
// in class Author; it is supposed that the list has name "bookList" in the class
public List<Book> getBookList()
{
    return new Collections.unmodifiableList(bookList); // not modifiable!
}
```

Second: you want book lists sorted in various ways; one solution is to create an enum:

```
public enum BookSort
{
    BY_NAME (new Comparator<Book>()
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(final Book a, final Book b)
        {
            return a.getName().compareTo(b.getName());
        }
    }),
    // other values

    private final Comparator<Book> comparator;

    BookSort(final Comparator<Book> comparator)
    {
        this.comparator = comparator;
    }

    // Return a sorted copy of books
    public List<Book> sort(final List<Book> list)
    {
        final List<Book> ret = new ArrayList<Book>(list);
        Collections.sort(ret, comparator);
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Then, in your code:

```
final List<Book> sorted = BookSort.BY_NAME.sort(original);
```

But all this code is moot to begin with if you do not provide the **full code** of both the `Author` and `Book` class; along with the existing mechanism to grab instances of these two classes.

Comment: +1 @viv you will find all explanations about 'fge' response in the *Joshua Bloch*'s book **Effective Java** http://www.amazon.com/Effective-Java-Edition-Joshua-Bloch/dp/0321356683 . If you want to write good and secure code, it is perhaps the only book you have to understand deeply

Comment: what elegant solution for the comparator. Last time I did those it wasn't near as nice looking as that.

Comment: Actually, it is even bettter to use an enum here.

Comment: @fge I'm trying my best to understand how a enum would be better. Unless you mean to have just one sort method with a switch in it. I think I would overload the sort method and have the second one pass in a comparator. This way you have a default sort (say by book id) and you can pass in a mock comparator if needed.

Comment: @RobertSnyder that is a design choice, really... I kind of don't like "data" classes which do too much :p Now, if the OP included his full code...